# precompiledapp.config - how do I create it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm having a problem with a web application where the events in the global.asax class aren't being executed when I build the application through our build server and publish the website. In Application_Start is a single line of code sets up our logging, and in Application_Error I have some error handling code. Locally it all works fine, and if I copy the files directly from my development folder to the server rather than publishing it via the build server everything works fine.

From loads of Googling it would appear that this is a problem with the precompiledapp.config file being missing - sure enough it doesn't exist anywhere. However, nowhere can I find out how I actually get the TFS Build Server, or Visual Studio (2010), to create this file so that I can publish it.

Any advice on how I can generate this file would be much appreciated.

EDIT: A bit more information. I've just tried publishing the website through Visual Studio 2010 rather than the build server and this created the precompiledapp.config file. I copied all the files across to the server (except web.config which I left intact) and it logs successfully (which suggests the global.ascx events are being fired). What I need to do now is try and get the build server to do the same thing - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your custom config file is set as a content file and Copy To Output is set to Always in the config file properties in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

The problem I have is that I don't have the config file as its not created anywhere. I've just tried copying it from my publish folder (where it does get created) into the root of my development folder, then checked it into TFS. I then ran a build hoping it would copy it to the output folder, but instead the build failed saying "This application is already precompiled".

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have resolved this issue now.

As I mentioned in the Edit of my original message, when I published the website through Visual Studio 2010 to a local folder it created the Precompiledapp.config file, and copying the folder contents to the test version of the application got everything working. As I can't seem to get the TFS Build server to create this file, I decided to try just copying the file from my local publish folder to the test application, along with the rest of the files from the tfs build, and everything seems to be working as it should.

So although I've not managed to figure out how to get the build server to generate this file, my main issue is resolved and I'm able to use the global.asax file again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this question BUT you should probably verify that you have the correct SDK that visual studio would use to build the precompiled app (I think it's Azure SDK even if not doing anything with Azure but not 100% on that).

If you have visual studio installed on the build server you can just install the web workload (opening the solution will prompt it). I did this with Visual Studio 2019 today. MSBuild was ignoring not only my *.pubxml settings but even passed in properties via command line arguments to msbuild.exe (which overwrite the ones in the *.pubxml file).

I opened Visual Studio, it prompted me to install the necessary workload and I did. Everything started working as expected after that.

To precompile, in your pubxml file make sure to have this:

```
<PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
```

Also, this post refers to your Edit comment about how to get the build server to do it when it works on your machine.